# How check if throwed exception

Tags: java

if i have something like this:

```
public User findUserByEmail(String email) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where email = ?").setParameter(0,email).list();

        if (users.size() > 0) {
            return users.get(0);
        } else {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

And in this moment i want to check the returned findUserByEmail(String email) method whether it return the User object or CustomerNotFoundException in the end.

I tried in this way

```
 private boolean searchCustomer(String email) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
            if (hibernateDao.findUserByEmail(email).getClass() == User.class) {
                .... 
            } else { .... }
        }
```

Is it a good way or are there betters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Nonononono.

Use the `catch` keyword to catch the `Exception`.

```
try {
   User thingie = hibernateDao.findUserByEmail(email);
}
catch (CustomerNotFoundException cnfe) {
    // TODO some logic on failure
}
```

Also remove the `throws` statement from your `searchCustomer` method's signature if you're using a `try` / `catch` mechanism and not rethrowing the `Exception`.